# Javascript document.getElement innerHTML undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, innerhtml

I am trying to make the outcome of a function appear in a  element outside the script. Instead of the outcome I get an "undefined" message. It is probably just a matter of syntax, but I don't get it to work.

Here is what I did:

```html
<html>
<head>


</head><body> 
<table class="mytable">    
<tr>

<p><span id="number1">1</span><span> + </span><span id="number2">2</span><span> = </span></p>

<p><span id="sr">here goes the range of solutions to select of</span></p>

<p><span id="quote">here goes the quote</span></p>
</table>
<form id="myForm">
<div id="display" style="height: 20px; width: 100%;"></div>
 
<script>

var plusorminus1 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
var plusorminus2 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
var plusorminus3 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
var plusorminus4 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
var plusorminus5 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
var plusorminus6 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
var plusorminus7 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;

function sortfunction(a, b){
    return (a - b) 
}

var number1;
var number2;

number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = number1;
document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = number2;

var answer = parseInt(number1,10)+parseInt(number2,10);

var addarr = []
while(addarr.length < 7){
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)
    if(addarr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    addarr[addarr.length] = randomnumber;
}

var var1 = answer;
var var2 = answer + (plusorminus1 * addarr[0]);
var var3 = answer + (plusorminus2 * addarr[1]);
var var4 = answer + (plusorminus3 * addarr[2]);
var var5 = answer + (plusorminus4 * addarr[3]);
var var6 = answer + (plusorminus5 * addarr[3]);
var var7 = answer + (plusorminus6 * addarr[3]);

var myarray=[var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7]; 
   myarray=myarray.sort(sortfunction);


for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
{
 var sr = (function(val) {
        btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.data = val;
        btn.innerHTML = val;
        btn.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
  return btn.data = val;
    })(myarray[i]);
document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = sr; //only shows the last value in the array
}


function checkAnswer(evt) {
    if (evt.target.data == answer) {
        display.innerHTML = ("correct");
    } else {
        display.innerHTML = ("Not correct");
    }
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = evt.target.data; //does not work
}
</script>

</FORM>


</body>
</html>
```

So, what I want is the following:
- show the range of answers to select from within the span above.
- show the answer (correct/not correct) in the span above.
Well, maybe it is possible to make the whole code more elegant, but these are my predominant problems here.

Comment: You don't return anything from the function you're setting `sr` to the value of.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting undefined is that you never `return` anything from the function which is assigned to the variable `sr` (and subsequently set as the content of a div with that same id)

```
var sr = (function(val) {
    btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.data = val;
    btn.innerHTML = val;
    btn.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
})(myarray[i]);
document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = sr;
              sr has the value undefined --^
```

It is not clear what you meant to put as the `innerHTML` of the div with an id of `sr`.

Comment: Got it. So, what can I do in order to get the whole array instead of the last element only when I put `return btn.data = val;` and then `document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = sr; `?

Answer (score 1):

You set the inner HTML to `sr`, which is the return value of the function:

```
var sr = (function(val) {
    // ...
    // nothing is returned
})(myarray[i]);

document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = sr;
```

But this function doesn't return anything!

Make it return something using the `return` keyword.

```
var sr = (function(val) {
    // ...
    return "I <3 Stack Overflow";
})(myarray[i]);
```

Comment: O.k. I changed the snippet above and put `return btn.data = val;`. Now it returns only the last value of the range. I wanted it to show the same as the range of buttons.